# React Native Scroll View with flex

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create a modal, which has 2 parts: `ScrollView` and `TouchableOpacity`.

So i used `react-native-modal` and my app.js:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View
} from "react-native";
import Modal from "react-native-modal";

export default class Example extends Component {
  state = {
    isModalVisible: false
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={() => this.setState({ isModalVisible: true })}
        >
          <View style={styles.button}>
            <Text>Open It!</Text>
          </View>
        </TouchableOpacity>

        <Modal
          isVisible={this.state.isModalVisible}
          onBackButtonPress={() => this.setState({ isModalVisible: false })}
        >
          <View style={styles.modalContent}>
            <View style={{ flex: 9 }}>
              <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
                <View style={{ flex: 3, backgroundColor: "red" }}>
                  <Text>A</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={{ flex: 2, backgroundColor: "yellow" }}>
                  <Text>B</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "green" }}>
                  <Text>C</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "blue" }}>
                  <Text>D</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "cyan" }}>
                  <Text>E</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "orange" }}>
                  <Text>F</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "orange" }}>
                  <Text>F</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "orange" }}>
                  <Text>F</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "orange" }}>
                  <Text>F</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "orange" }}>
                  <Text>F</Text>
                </View>

                <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "orange" }}>
                  <Text>F</Text>
                </View>
              </ScrollView>
            </View>
            <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
              <TouchableOpacity
                style={styles.button}
                onPress={() => this.setState({ isModalVisible: false })}
              >
                <Text>Add Package</Text>
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
        </Modal>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center"
  },

  button: {
    backgroundColor: "lightblue",
    padding: 12,
    margin: 16,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)"
  },

  modalContent: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "white",
    padding: 22,
    justifyContent: "center",
    alignItems: "center",
    borderRadius: 4,
    borderColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)"
  }
});
```

But now it's unscrollable! I tried to remove the `flexGrow: 1` but then the child's `flex: x` lose its effect!

Please consider that **I DON'T WANT to use height and width**!

Any idea?

> Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you have `flex: 9`? do you really need that? why is the scroll view inside a wrapping view? just use the scroll view give it a `flex: 1`... then on the button view that you want to be a more fixed height (im assuming its fixed to the bottom of the device's screen) give it a `flex: 0` with `flexBasis: auto`

Comment: @JohnRuddell I've `flex: 9` since i want my scroll view 9x bigger than my button - I've also tried to remove that wrapping `<View>` but not result!

Comment: why do you want it 9x bigger? you should let the content fill the area and let the content define the height

Comment: @JohnRuddell that's my layout design! If i have a `<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>` wrapper then I want to have two views: the first is 9x and the second is 1x

Comment: But when you specify flex values you realize that the component doesn't scroll anymore right? you are setting its height. flex says fill the available space by a unit size. `flex: 1` is one unit size for an element. that size changes depending on how many siblings an element has. [**See here for a working example of your code**](https://snack.expo.io/@jruddell/petrified-candy) ... heart of it is.. let your content fill the space. let the scrollview do its thing (dont specify flex).

Comment: Right - So how can i achieve that? I want two views in my scroll view: A with 3x and B with 1x - You add three `A` Text... i want a single view...

Comment: i just added a few to give some visual contrast. I'm not sure what exactly `A with 3x and B with 1x` means. you had 11 views inside your scrollview in your example

Comment: I want  A view with flex 3 and B view with flex 1 so if i use them in a normal `<View>`, I'll see A is 3 times bigger than B

Comment: ok so just specify exactly what you said. flex 3 is 3 times bigger than flex 1